# How to solve JLabel error?

Tags: java, swing

I went for a little java project but got stuck. When using java swing, I could not add a label (JLabel). The code was something like this:

```
JFrame frm = new JFrame("frame");
JLabel label = new JLabel("test text");
frm.add(label);
```

There occurs an error while doing this. When I put my cursor over it, eclipse suggests me to configure build path.
Again I can run the exact same code in netbeans. How do I solve it???

Comment: Just read your code twice...

Answer (score 0):

```
Jlabel label = new JLabel("test text"); 
frm.add(jlab);
```

The label object reference you have created and the reference you are adding to the frame are different. Edit it as below and check again.

```
frm.add(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're keeping `JLabel` object reference in `Jlabel` it should be `JLabel`

```
JFrame frm = new JFrame("frame");
JLabel label = new JLabel("test text");         
frm.add(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse complains because of two problems in your code snippet:

1. There is no `Jlabel` class in `swing` package. There is one called `JLabel` instead.
2. There is no variable called `jlab` in the local scope. There is one called 'label` instead.

**Replace**

```
Jlabel label = new JLabel("test text");
frm.add(jlab);
```

**with**

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("test text");
frm.add(label);
```